# Error on line 1 at column 1; Document is empty?

Tags: php, sql, xampp

I'm trying to output an XML file with the data from my SQL database. I keep getting the error "Error on line 1 column 1: Document is empty... "

I have looked through similar questions and solutions states to move the

```html
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

to the top of the file before anything else. Which I have now done - but I still get the error.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong with this?

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

require("config.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "test1 \n\n";
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
echo "test2 \n\n";

if($resultCheck > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['id'] . "<br>";
   echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
   echo $row['address'] . "<br>";
   echo $row['lat'] . "<br>";
   echo $row['lng'] . "<br>";
   echo $row['type'] . "<br>";
  }
 }
echo "test3 \n\n";
// Start XML file, echo parent node

$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}

//End XML file
echo '</markers>';



?>
```

Note - my connection to database line creating

```html
$connection
```

is in my config file.

NOTE - I am in the process of testing through the code, hence some are commented out here and there with random test statements, I just cant get to the reason for the error!

Comment: Can you post the full error you are getting. `"Error on line x... "` isn't that helpful lol

Comment: Error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty - thats the current error. Before moving it was Error on line x ... cant remember the rest, one moment

Comment: Your `parseToXML` and the majority of your code within your while loop are commented out?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am in the process of testing through the code, which is why some is commented out. I'll go through and remove the commented out parts

Comment: It is no longer commented out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This page contains the following error: error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747607/this-page-contains-the-following-error-error-on-line-1-at-column-1-document-is)